# Are JQuery selectors limited to the current modal window? I am having problems retrieving data from a modal behind the current one

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, modal-dialog

I am using JQuery's data method to store some information in an app.

Setting the data and then checking it is set is working fine.

```
var my_data = "sample data";

var data_location = $("#data_location");

$.data(data_location, "my_data", my_value);

console.log("data: " + $.data(data_location, "my_data"));
```

This would output to my console: "sample data".

The data is being stored to a div (#data_location) in a modal dialog that is visible.

The app then sometimes displays a second modal dialog over top of the first (data containing) modal window.

Once the second modal dialog is displayed I don't seem to be able to retrieve the data.

From the second dialog I am running:

```
var data_location = $("#data_location");

console.log("data: " + $.data(data_location, "my_data"));
```

When this is run with the second modal dialog display it outputs "undefined".

Is there something limiting my JQuery selector to the current modal dialog?

Or am I missing something else?

Thanks for your assistance.

JS fiddle demonstrating the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/tNEAX/36/

Interestingly, if I set the data location outside of the two click events it does work.  Unfortunately I can't do this because I am working between multiple js files.  You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/tNEAX/39/

Comment: Can you post a fiddle or jsbin?

Comment: You don't mention what techniques you're using to do the modals.  If they are just divs, then what you are doing should work.  If there are iframes involved though, then your technique will exhibit the results you are seeing.

Comment: Hi Pete, I've added a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tNEAX/36/

Comment: Hi Steve.  The modals are made off divs, no iFrames.

Comment: Have you tried putting `var data_location = $("#data_location");` outside of the events?

Comment: Hi Paul,  yes I have and that does work.  Unfortunately both events are in separate files ... although there might be something I can do with that... will give it a try

Comment: So, as Paul suggested, this does work when I put the var data_location = $("#data_location"); outside of the events themselves.  Because each of the events are in separate files I've had to put setting of the data_location var in the main document before those are loaded.  Can anyone explain what is causing the selector to not work when it is in the event?  Thanks.